# ffmpeg overlay doesn't show at all when using fade filter but instantly showing when not using fade filter

Tags: ffmpeg

**Command where input #2 doesn't fade in (this works OK but I need to fade it in).**

```
time ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -loop 1 -t 21 -i 6e81d7a2e2979f10c531af8276d8136f.jpg -loop 1 -t 9 -i b28fd2813e9384353710402a9a450cd7.jpg -i bad861c0fd5f6a1e73b582749a56852b.jpg.png -t 29 -ss -1 -i 1633189093.mp3 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -filter_complex " [3:a]afade=t=out:st=24:d=5[a]; [0:v]\n' +
'            scale=878:494\n' +
'              :force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\n' +
'            pad=\n' +
'              width=878\n' +
'              :height=494\n' +
'              :x=(ow-iw)/2\n' +
'              :y=(oh-ih)/2\n' +
'              :color=0x000000,\n' +
'            setsar=1[image0];\n' +
'          [1:v]\n' +
'            scale=878:494\n' +
'              :force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\n' +
'            pad=\n' +
'              width=878\n' +
'              :height=494\n' +
'              :x=(ow-iw)/2\n' +
'              :y=(oh-ih)/2\n' +
'              :color=0x000000,\n' +
'            setsar=1[image1];\n' +
'          [image0][image1]\n' +
'            xfade=transition=fade\n' +
'              :duration=1\n' +
`              :offset=20[video]; [video]fade=in:0:25[video]; [video]split=2[base][blurred]; [blurred]boxblur=luma_radius=5:luma_power=1[blurred]; [blurred]fade=type=in:start_time=1:duration=2:alpha=1[blurred-with-fadein]; [base][blurred-with-fadein]overlay[video]; [video]drawbox= x=0 :y=0 :w=iw :h=ih :color=0x000000@0.3 :t='fill' :enable='between(t,3,29)'[video]; [2:v]scale=-2:247:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase[scaledCoverPhoto]; [video][scaledCoverPhoto]overlay=:x=w/2:y=(H-h)/2 , subtitles=intro-INTRO-subtitle.ass:fontsdir=../../preview/fonts,  format=yuv420p, scale=-2:494 " -shortest -map "[a]" -format hls -sn -hls_time 5 -strict -2 -vsync 2 -bufsize 1200k -hls_list_size 0 -g 4 -r 25 output/index.m3u8
```

**Command where I need input #2 to fade in at second 6 for duration 1 second (but it doesn't work)**

```
time ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -loop 1 -t 21 -i 6e81d7a2e2979f10c531af8276d8136f.jpg -loop 1 -t 9 -i b28fd2813e9384353710402a9a450cd7.jpg -i bad861c0fd5f6a1e73b582749a56852b.jpg.png -t 29 -ss -1 -i 1633189093.mp3 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -filter_complex " [3:a]afade=t=out:st=24:d=5[a]; [0:v]\n' +
'            scale=878:494\n' +
'              :force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\n' +
'            pad=\n' +
'              width=878\n' +
'              :height=494\n' +
'              :x=(ow-iw)/2\n' +
'              :y=(oh-ih)/2\n' +
'              :color=0x000000,\n' +
'            setsar=1[image0];\n' +
'          [1:v]\n' +
'            scale=878:494\n' +
'              :force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\n' +
'            pad=\n' +
'              width=878\n' +
'              :height=494\n' +
'              :x=(ow-iw)/2\n' +
'              :y=(oh-ih)/2\n' +
'              :color=0x000000,\n' +
'            setsar=1[image1];\n' +
'          [image0][image1]\n' +
'            xfade=transition=fade\n' +
'              :duration=1\n' +
`              :offset=20[video]; [video]fade=in:0:25[video]; [video]split=2[base][blurred]; [blurred]boxblur=luma_radius=5:luma_power=1[blurred]; [blurred]fade=type=in:start_time=1:duration=2:alpha=1[blurred-with-fadein]; [base][blurred-with-fadein]overlay[video]; [video]drawbox= x=0 :y=0 :w=iw :h=ih :color=0x000000@0.3 :t='fill' :enable='between(t,3,29)'[video]; [2:v]scale=-2:247:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,format=rgba,fade=in:st=6:d=1:alpha=1[scaledCoverPhoto]; [video][scaledCoverPhoto]overlay=:x=w/2:y=(H-h)/2 , subtitles=intro-INTRO-subtitle.ass:fontsdir=../../preview/fonts,  format=yuv420p, scale=-2:494 " -shortest -map "[a]" -format hls -sn -hls_time 5 -strict -2 -vsync 2 -bufsize 1200k -hls_list_size 0 -g 4 -r 25 output/index.m3u8
```

Input #2 is not fading in and not showing at all. What am I doing wrong? I've spent more than a couple of hours in research and trials.

Please note that the second command is different than the first one, only through this added line `format=rgba,fade=in:st=6:d=1:alpha=1`.

Thank you very much!

Second command output:

```
"Input #0, image2, from '6e81d7a2e2979f10c531af8276d8136f.jpg':\n" +
'  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3201 kb/s\n' +
'  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 878x494 [SAR 96:96 DAR 439:247], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc\n' +
"Input #1, image2, from 'b28fd2813e9384353710402a9a450cd7.jpg':\n" +
'  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6376 kb/s\n' +
'  Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 878x494 [SAR 96:96 DAR 439:247], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc\n' +
"Input #2, png_pipe, from 'bad861c0fd5f6a1e73b582749a56852b.jpg.png':\n" +
'  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A\n' +
'  Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 431x514 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 431:514], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc\n' +
'[mp3 @ 0x7fbaea819800] invalid concatenated file detected - using bitrate for duration\n' +
'[mp3 @ 0x7fbaea819800] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate\n' +
'1633189093.mp3: could not seek to position -0.975\n' +
"Input #3, mp3, from '1633189093.mp3':\n" +
'  Metadata:\n' +
'    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100\n' +
'  Duration: 00:14:57.93, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s\n' +
'  Stream #3:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      encoder         : Lavf\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] libass API version: 0x1501000\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] libass source: tarball: 0.15.1\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.10 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 2.8.2 (COMPLEX)\n' +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/quicksand-bold.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/fjallaone-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/signika-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/lato-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/philosopher-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/quicksand-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/gentiumbasic-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/mavenpro-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/comingsoon-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/overlock-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/tangerine-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/gentiumbasic-italic.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/alegreya-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/dancingscript-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/courgette-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/opensans-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/lora-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/pontanosans-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/cambo-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/cantataone-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf'\n" +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Using font provider coretext\n' +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Track has custom format line(s). 'ScaledBorderAndShadow' will default to 'yes'.\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbae8f1c940] Track has custom format line(s). 'ScaledBorderAndShadow' will default to 'yes'.\n" +
'Codec AVOption format (set pixel type) specified for output file #0 (output/index.m3u8) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.\n' +
'Stream mapping:\n' +
'  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> scale\n' +
'  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> scale\n' +
'  Stream #2:0 (png) -> scale\n' +
'  Stream #3:0 (mp3float) -> afade\n' +
'  scale -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)\n' +
'  afade -> Stream #0:1 (aac)\n' +
'Press [q] to stop, [?] for help\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] libass API version: 0x1501000\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] libass source: tarball: 0.15.1\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.10 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 2.8.2 (COMPLEX)\n' +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/quicksand-bold.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/fjallaone-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/signika-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/lato-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/philosopher-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/quicksand-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/gentiumbasic-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/mavenpro-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/comingsoon-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/overlock-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/tangerine-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/gentiumbasic-italic.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/alegreya-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/dancingscript-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/courgette-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/opensans-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/lora-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/pontanosans-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/cambo-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/cantataone-regular.ttf'\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Loading font file '../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf'\n" +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Using font provider coretext\n' +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Track has custom format line(s). 'ScaledBorderAndShadow' will default to 'yes'.\n" +
"[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] Track has custom format line(s). 'ScaledBorderAndShadow' will default to 'yes'.\n" +
'[swscaler @ 0x7fbad8390000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly\n' +
'[swscaler @ 0x7fbad8598000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] VBV bufsize set but maxrate unspecified, ignored\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] using SAR=1/1\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=4 keyint_min=1 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0\n' +
"Output #0, hls, to 'output/index.m3u8':\n" +
'  Metadata:\n' +
'    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100\n' +
'  Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 878x494 [SAR 1:1 DAR 439:247], q=2-31, 25 fps, 90k tbn (default)\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264\n' +
'    Side data:\n' +
'      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 1200000 vbv_delay: N/A\n' +
'  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac\n' +
"frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    \rframe=   33 fps=0.0 q=14.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.23 bitrate=N/A speed=2.44x    \rframe=   75 fps= 74 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.90 bitrate=N/A speed=2.87x    \rframe=  110 fps= 72 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.29 bitrate=N/A speed=2.83x    \r[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index0.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
'frame=  146 fps= 72 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.76 bitrate=N/A speed=2.85x    \r[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] fontselect: (Arial, 400, 0) -> /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Arial.ttf, -1, ArialMT\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] fontselect: (Open Sans, 400, 0) -> OpenSans-Regular, 0, OpenSans-Regular\n' +
'[Parsed_subtitles_18 @ 0x7fbaeb014340] fontselect: (Greate Vibes, 400, 0) -> /System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.ttc, -1, Helvetica\n' +
"frame=  173 fps= 69 q=13.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.85 bitrate=N/A speed=2.71x    \rframe=  201 fps= 66 q=13.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.94 bitrate=N/A speed=2.61x    \rframe=  230 fps= 65 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.10 bitrate=N/A speed=2.56x    \rframe=  258 fps= 63 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.21 bitrate=N/A speed=2.51x    \r[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index1.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"frame=  287 fps= 63 q=10.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.40 bitrate=N/A speed=2.49x    \rframe=  314 fps= 62 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.47 bitrate=N/A speed=2.45x    \rframe=  342 fps= 61 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.60 bitrate=N/A speed=2.43x    \rframe=  372 fps= 61 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.79 bitrate=N/A speed=2.42x    \r[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index2.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"frame=  402 fps= 61 q=11.0 size=N/A time=00:00:16.00 bitrate=N/A speed=2.42x    \rframe=  436 fps= 61 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:17.34 bitrate=N/A speed=2.44x    \rframe=  471 fps= 62 q=10.0 size=N/A time=00:00:18.74 bitrate=N/A speed=2.46x    \rframe=  505 fps= 62 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:20.11 bitrate=N/A speed=2.47x    \r[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index3.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"frame=  536 fps= 62 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:21.34 bitrate=N/A speed=2.47x    \rframe=  572 fps= 62 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:22.78 bitrate=N/A speed=2.49x    \rframe=  608 fps= 63 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:24.22 bitrate=N/A speed=2.51x    \rframe=  636 fps= 63 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:25.38 bitrate=N/A speed= 2.5x    \r[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index4.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"frame=  665 fps= 62 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:26.51 bitrate=N/A speed=2.48x    \rframe=  694 fps= 62 q=13.0 size=N/A time=00:00:27.68 bitrate=N/A speed=2.47x    \r[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index5.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fbaec008a00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
'frame=  725 fps= 62 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:29.00 bitrate=N/A speed=2.48x    \n' +
'video:6428kB audio:436kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] frame I:182   Avg QP:10.92  size: 32343\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] frame P:543   Avg QP:13.83  size:  1280\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] mb P  I16..4:  4.7%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  9.4%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:85.9%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 77.6% 37.0% 27.4% inter: 3.1% 2.5% 0.0%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] i16 v,h,dc,p: 27% 30%  9% 34%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] i8c dc,h,v,p: 54% 24% 16%  6%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fbaec009000] kb/s:1815.52\n' +
'[aac @ 0x7fbaec012a00] Qavg: 1057.250\n' +
'\n' +
'real\t0m11.791s\n' +
'user\t0m13.176s\n' +
'sys\t0m0.540s'
```

Comment: I think I've managed to make it work by looping the actual input #2. Would that be the correct fix? Thank you!

Comment: That's probably it. Suggestions for next time to help your questions not be ignored: 1) Never use `-hide_banner` when asking for help. It hides important info often needed for providing answers. 2) Make it as easy as possible for someone to help. We couldn't simply copy and paste your command to try it out. 3) Show the simplest command that still has the problem. It will be easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @llogan for your wise words and help, as always! I'll keep that in mind but in this situation it would have been really difficult for me to strip down all the options. I'll do my best next time.